# Is it a poor practice to create a single Class/Enum of all possible local Intent actions?

Tags: android, android-intent

I was wondering if it was considered poor practice to create a single java `class` or `enum` that contained all my application's different `Intent` actions. If not in a `class` or `enum`, then maybe one of the `XML` files? I plan on using [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to handle events to decrease coupling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see anything particularly 'good' but surely it is possible to have a utility class consisting of `public static final Strings` representing your actions. It should then have a `private` constructor and you will not want to subclass from that class.

I wouldn't put the constants in an `interface` though because you will have to `implement` that interface then but what you want is usage and not the implementation.

There's an advice in ['Effective Java'](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) to avoid purely constant interfaces.

Comment: Yep, seen the book. Still, I'm wondering about whether or not it's okay to dump all possible event names into a single enum. My other option is to split them up based on which classes throw what events, which would then couple the subscribers to the publishers, rendering one of my main goals pointless. Thanks!

Comment: @cesar Having them within the publishers is also not bad. If they are all in a single class then one time you remove one of the publishers and forget to remove a corresponding string from that utility class. Nothing bad either but anyway.

Comment: @/\ "you will have to implement that interface then but what you want is usage and not the implementation."
is it must to implement Interface!! to access some constants defined in it??

Comment: @Alex: I don't think you need to implement the interface to use one of its fields if it's `public static final`, still, I remember it being bad, but don't know exactly why.

As for putting the event action constants in the publishers, that would couple the publishing objects to the subscribing objects to a point, and that's what I am trying to avoid, so yeah...

Comment: @Ankit, no surely you don't have to implement the interface but then an interface can not have a private constructor so an interface can not be a utility class neither

Comment: Yes that for sure, But we can define constants in Interface as Interface's fields is by default public static and final. so can access them either implementing or by Interfacename.Field name. I have seen many places in Android source code, defining constants in interface..

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is Good to have all Intent Action in a single Java ***Class***, or you can have ***Interface*** for it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Mind justifying it, please?

Comment: It is always recommended in java to have a constant util class/interface which should contains all the related constants. Which improve readability. And if you want to change anything, You don't need search whole source code for particular fields. am i making any sense!!

Comment: and it is recommended to have constant's name in caps.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you meant, but Alex's answer was a bit more complete (with a source and everything). I also have to agree with his statement about interfaces being bad for these things.

Comment: Yes thanks, but don't make ur mind that Interface need to implemented to access constants, Even source code of OS, defined constants in interface!!!